# Verify selected dropdown value

Tags: java, selenium

I am developing test automation in Selenium using Java, where in form field value is being selected from auto-suggest dropdown. How can I verify my selection whether field has some value or empty.
I found solution to this is

```
if(elementLocator.getAttribute("value").isEmpty(){   
    System.out.println("Field is empty");   
}
```

Since there no attribute called "value" present, the above code is not working.
I am pasting below piece of my code where if value is being selected, `attribute area-selected="true"` is shown.

```
<div class="Select-control">  

<span id="react-select-22--value" class="Select-multi-value-wrapper">

<div class="Select-value">

<span id="react-select-22--value-item" class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true">India</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("div#Select-value > span")).getText();

Comment: hi, solution given by you did not work, though i got the idea how to do. I tried     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='Select-value']/span")).getText() , but problem is if the field is empty, it wont get displayed. and selenium is unable to find it.

Comment: yup i missed that it was class :  `driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("div.Select-value > span")).getText();` hash needed to be replaced with dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know how to solve this.

I used `try` and `catch` block, which helped me when none of the other solution `isDiplayed()`,`isEmpty()`, `size()>0` worked.

Below is the solution according to which, find your element with `try` block, if it is there, do your action, else throw error with `catch` block. This solution is helpful even if the element is dynamically appearing in the application.

```
try{
    String Gender=findElement(By.xpath("yourElementPath")).getText();
    System.out.println("Input field has value = "+Gender);
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.error("Input field 'Gender' is empty");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is some drop down, the below code can give you some idea.

```
WebElement month_dropdown=driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
Select month=new Select(month_dropdown);
WebElement first_value=month.getFirstSelectedOption();
String value=first_value.getText()
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: As you can see in his shared code, it's not a select tag

Comment: What does getText() returns

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='react-select-22--value-item']")).getText();

Comment: Text within a tag or its child